# THREEJS - Indexed BufferGeometry with 2 materials

Tags: three.js

I want to create ONE single buffer geometry that can hold many materials.
I have read that in order to achieve this in BufferGeometry, I need to use groups. So I created the following "floor" mesh:

```js
var gg=new THREE.BufferGeometry(),vtx=[],fc=[[],[]],mm=[
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color:0xff0000 }),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color:0x0000ff })
];
for(var y=0 ; y<11 ; y++)
    for(var x=0 ; x<11 ; x++) {
        vtx.push(x-5,0,y-5);
        if(x&&y) {
            var p=(vtx.length/3)-1;
            fc[(x%2)^(y%2)].push(
                 p,p-11,p-1,
                 p-1,p-11,p-12
            );
        }
    }
gg.addAttribute('position',new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vtx,3));
Array.prototype.push.apply(fc[0],fc[1]); gg.setIndex(fc[0]);
gg.computeVertexNormals();
gg.addGroup(0,100,0);
gg.addGroup(100,100,1);
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(gg,mm));
```

## THE ISSUE:

- looking at the example in https://www.crazygao.com/vc/tst2.htm can see that the BLUE material looks weird.
- Single material showup OK.
- 2 materials with group as above, in any case show the BLUE really strage.
- Changing the 1st group to start=0, count=200 (for all triangles) and removing the 2nd group, will show MORE squares of RED (obviously) but still NOT in the way I would like it to show.
- Changing the 1st group count to any value greater than 200 will cause a crash (obviously) of attempting to access vertex out of range...

## Is anyone know clearly what shall I do?

I am using THREE.js v.101 and I prefer to not create special custom shader for that, or add another vertex buffer to duplicate those I already have, and I prefer to not create 2 meshes as this may get much more complicated with advanced models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this: https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/zebos3va/

[image: three.js BufferGeometry groups example]

---

**fix #1** - don't define group 0

**fix #2** - 2nd parameter in `.addGroup` is buffer length, it must be multiple of 3 (100 was wrong)

```js
var gg = new THREE.BufferGeometry(),
    vtx = [],
    fc = [[],[]],
    mm = [
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xff0000
        }),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0x0000ff
        })
    ];

for (var y = 0; y < 11; y++)
    for (var x = 0; x < 11; x++) {
        vtx.push(x - 5, 0, y - 5);
        if (x && y) {
            var p = (vtx.length / 3) - 1;
            fc[(x % 2) ^ (y % 2)].push(
                p, p - 11, p - 1,
                p - 1, p - 11, p - 12
            );
        }
    }

gg.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vtx, 3));
fc[0].push.apply(fc[1]);
gg.setIndex(fc[0]);
gg.computeVertexNormals();

// group 0 is everything, unless you define group 1
// fix #1 - don't define group 0
// fix #2 - 2nd parameter is buffer length, it must be multiple of 3 (100 was wrong)

gg.addGroup(0, 102, 1);

scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(gg, mm));
```

Comment: Yes, this gave me the correct direction for move about the buffer length - though I had mistake in my code using [].push.apply instead of Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1,arr2) to achieve the goal.