# Applying multiple textures to same geometry

Tags: three.js

I have planeGeometry and I have some vertices higher than others, so some vertices have different z index to generate terrain-like texture.

I want to add different textures like grass,sand,snow to different planes.

How can I add to material to different planes.

This is how planegeometry is generated.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/geometries/PlaneGeometry.js

```
    var indices = [];
    var vertices = [];
    var normals = [];
    var uvs = [];

    // generate vertices, normals and uvs

    for ( iy = 0; iy < gridY1; iy ++ ) {
        var y = iy * segment_height - height_half;
        for ( ix = 0; ix < gridX1; ix ++ ) {
            var x = ix * segment_width - width_half;
            vertices.push( x, - y, 0 );
            normals.push( 0, 0, 1 );
            uvs.push( ix / gridX );
            uvs.push( 1 - ( iy / gridY ) );
        }
    }

    // indices

    for ( iy = 0; iy < gridY; iy ++ ) {

        for ( ix = 0; ix < gridX; ix ++ ) {
            var a = ix + gridX1 * iy;
            var b = ix + gridX1 * ( iy + 1 );
            var c = ( ix + 1 ) + gridX1 * ( iy + 1 );
            var d = ( ix + 1 ) + gridX1 * iy;
            // faces
            indices.push( a, b, d );
            indices.push( b, c, d );
        }
    }

    // build geometry

    this.setIndex( indices );
    this.addAttribute( 'position', new Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
    this.addAttribute( 'normal', new Float32BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );
    this.addAttribute( 'uv', new Float32BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );
```

This is how it should be done:

```
//Loading in Texture:

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load('grass.jpg');
//Creating material:

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
    overdraw: true,
    wireframe: false
});
var materials = [];
materials.push(material);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
// Applying this one to faces that need certain material:
// https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.addGroup
geometry.addGroup();
```

Basically what I need is even adding texture to the first plane, but it always adds texture to the whole geometry,
then I can create loop myself which does create textures for rest.

Comment: this may bring you a step closer to the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177718/threejs-indexed-buffergeometry-with-2-materials/55179723#55179723

Comment: Alternate approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880715/texture-splatting-with-three-js